# CSS Only Content-Length Dependent Parallax

Tags: html, css, transform, parallax

Many clever people have found ways to achieve [a parallax effect in pure CSS3](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/). The core of most of these techniques is setting a perspective and `overflow-y` on a container element:

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And then on the top-most element setting:

```
.top {
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

And on the bottom element setting:

```
.bottom {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

Where a more negative `translateZ` indicates slower scrolling and `scale` is `perspective + -1 * translateZ`.

This works well, but surprisingly, achieving the following effect proves difficult.

Given two content blocks, a background and a foreground, of varying widths (it is possible for height of the background > height of the foreground, height of the foreground > height of the background, or even height of the background = height of the foreground), use `transform` to create a parallax effect where the following holds:

1. The main content (foreground) scrolls normally (as if it was regular content). In other words, page scrolling correlates directly to scrolling the content.
2. As you scroll, the background content scrolls appropriate (faster, slower, or the same speed as the foreground) such that when the bottom of the foreground content is reached, the background content has scrolled completely to the bottom as well.

I have determined the following:

- The `translateZ` and `scale` property are dependent on the ratio of the foreground to background heights and/or the height of the document (because of this javascript is necessary to do these calculations, but I would prefer to not just outsource everything to javascript and attach an onscroll since the browser can likely do it much more efficiently).
- For the foreground content to scroll normally, the the background must have a `translateZ` between `0px` and `1px`.
- For the background to maintain the correct scale, `Abs(translateZ) + scale = 1`.

To simplify the problem, I chose to first tackle the case when the background height is twice the foreground height. Logically, `translateZ(0.5px) scale(0.5)` should work, but it fails to line the background and foreground when the page is scrolled to the bottom.

I've also done some experimenting with trying to figure out a linear function to predict the proper values for these given the document, foreground, and background height, but I couldn't find a function which produced correct numbers for anything but the x=0 case (the one that I manually determined by manipulating the values in Dev Tools).

You can see [the results of my trials](http://jsbin.com/lopumaqulapu/1). Light grey is the foreground. The dark grey is the background. The parallel lines are to ensure that the transform does not distort the scaling of the background. The red outlines mark the top and bottom of each of the content blocks. To satisfy the above, when completely scrolled the red line at the bottom of the background and foreground must be the last pixel visible at the bottom of the viewport (this is not the case now).

I've also consulted the [W3C Spec on CSS Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#mathematical-description), but the mathematical definitions don't lead to an obvious mapping between `translateZ` and scroll speed.

So given all of this: **is there a function that given the heights of the document, background, foreground, it returns the appropriate `translateZ` and `scale` such that the points above hold?**